# urls redirection from domain to sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, subdomain, url-rewriting

i reinstall my server and don't want to loose my old content.
I'm working now with joomla 2.5 and my old install was on joomla 1.5.
My problem is : how to redirect these urls :

1)www.domain.com/TableView/a/    TO   www.domain.com/archives/index.php/TableView/a/
2)www.domain.com/Page-3.html     TO www.domain.com/archives/index.php/Page-3.html

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(TableView/a/)$ /archives/index.php/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(Page-3.html)$ /archives/index.php/$1 [R=302,L]
```